# How to solve ORA-02014: cannot select FOR UPDATE from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY

Tags: oracle, ora-02014

I want to lock a group of records using the following query:

```
select *
  from (select *
          from event_table
         where status = 'S'
        order by creation_data asc
       )
 where rownum <=10
for update;
```

---

event_table is not a view.  It is a regular table:

```
create table event_table
(
 id            number, 
 creation_date date, 
 status        number, 
 info          clob
);
```

The primary key is the field id.

Can I use `rownum` with `select for update` at all?

Is there another solution where using `select for update` but also selecting just a group of rows and not all the results from the select?

For example, I have a task that runs every X internal and needs to use `select for update` for that table, but if the select returns 500 rows, I just want to handle 100 of them each time (kind of paging).  That is why I tried `rownum` for that.

Thanks.

Comment: event_table may not be a view, but `(SELECT * FROM event_table...)` is a "view" in the context of this error message.

Comment: A query in the from clause is called an Inline View. http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Inline_view

Answer (score 19):

Does this work?:

```
select * from event_table where id in 
(
    SELECT id
    FROM (SELECT *
        FROM event_table
        WHERE status = 'S'
        ORDER BY CREATION_DATA ASC)
        WHERE ROWNUM <=10
)
FOR UPDATE;
```

Comment: well, the query succeeded, i'll check it now if the rows are locked as needed. thanks a lot.